# How to create task based on Case Owner in process builder?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have some complex scenario which I am unable to achieve it. Here the below user stories I received from client.

User Story:
*If the case has been in the status of '**Pending Decision**' for 30 days and case owner is in queue, Task should be generated under the case. Task Owner should be assigned to '**Derrick James**'. If the case has been in the status of 'Pending Decision' for 30 days and case owner is in '**Rahul Rathore**' (or someone other), Task should be generated under the case. Task Owner should be assigned to '**Case Owner**'.*

I have done the above scenario in process builder. I am not able to assign the task owner since it has two scenario. I need to implement this configuration within a week. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guys, After digging lots of blog. Here I'm providing links which can be useful in future. [Using Begins function](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193594/how-do-i-determine-if-the-case-owner-is-a-user-or-queue-in-process-builder) and [Using Left function](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225267/process-builder-error-ownerqueue-developername-is-causing-an-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging lots of blog. Here I'm providing links which can be useful in future. [Using Begins function](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193594/how-do-i-determine-if-the-case-owner-is-a-user-or-queue-in-process-builder) and [Using Left function](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225267/process-builder-error-ownerqueue-developername-is-causing-an-error)